# Ordering an RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider

```
val animals = List("penguin","ferret","cat").toSeq
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(animals, 1)
```

I would like to order this RDD. I'm new to Scala and a little confused about how this is to be done.

Comment: I have no knowledge about spark but maybe this is your answer:
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-sort-an-RDD-td1922.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDD documentation can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD). Look at `sortBy`:

```
sortBy[K](
  f: (T) ⇒ K, 
  ascending: Boolean = true, 
  numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.size
)
```

The `K` is the type of the snippet of the RDD you are sorting by. `f` is a function, which you can either define elsewhere with `def` and pass it by name or you can create one anonymously in line (which is more scala-like). `ascending` and `numPartitions` should be self explanatory.

So given all this, try:

```
rdd.sortBy[String]({animal => animal})
```

Then try this:

```
rdd.sortBy[String]({animal => animal}, false)
```

And then this one, which sorts the RDD by the number of letters "e" in the name of the animal, from most to least:

```
rdd.sortBy[Int]({a => a.split("").filter(char => char == "e").size}, false)
```

It should be noted that the original `rdd` isn't sorted -- a new, sorted RDD is returned by the operation.

Comment: So in the first case we just return what we give but we observe an alphabetical ordering, why is this? What does it have to do with the implicit Ordering[K]?

Comment: It follows the default Ordering[K], where K is the same as the K in sortBy[K]. You can override Ordering[K] I believe, but I never had a need to.

Comment: Seems like you could just omit the anonymous function altogether in this case? That's part of what has been confusing me, but I do understand what you have laid out and it has been very helpful.

Comment: The anonymous function just lets you pick out the part of the RDD line to use to compare. Yes in your example it is trivial since it uses the whole line. But you could do other more interesting things if you need to.

Comment: Aha the part of the RDD lime that makes much more sense. I tried passing in _ but it throws an error, shouldn't that just use the whole line?